# Unable to perform XPath operation. A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of concat()

Tags: xml, xpath

The XML is

```
<alumno id="a01">
            <apellido1>Cervantes</apellido1>
            <apellido2>Saavedra</apellido2>
            <nombre>Miguel</nombre>
            <sexo>Hombre</sexo>
            <estudios>
                <ciclo codigo="c01"/>
                <modulos>
                    <modulo codigo="m3009"/>
                    <modulo codigo="m0005"/>
                </modulos>
            </estudios>
</alumno>
```

I am trying to concat it that it shows "nombre apellido1 apellido2" with `concat(//alumno/nombre, //alumno/apellido1, //alumno/apellido2)`
but returns me the error:
`Unable to perform XPath operation. A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of concat() (<nombre/>, <nombre/>, <nombre/>, ...)`

By the way, there is more than one < alumno >.

Comment: Please show an input document with more than one `alumno`, indicating what output you expect your expression to produce. It's easy to tell you why it's failing, it's harder to tell you how to correct it, because you haven't said what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual XML probably has more than one `alumno` with different `id`s. So you need to concat at each `alumno` level separately (and add spaces). Try

```
//alumno/concat(nombre," ", ./apellido1," ", ./apellido2)
```

on your actual XML and see if it works.